# Are there any disadvantages in using a Makefile.am over setup.py?

Tags: python, c++, autotools, automake, distutils

I'm working on transitioning a project from scons to autotools, since I it seems to automatically generate a lot of features that are annoying to write in a SConscript (e.g. `make uninstall`).

The project is mostly c++ based, but also includes some modules that have been written in python. After a lot of reading autotools, I can finally create a shared library, compile and link an executable against it, and install c++ header files. Lovely. Now comes they python part. By including AM_PYTHON_PATH in configure.ac, I'm also installing the python modules with Makefile.am files such as

`autopy_PYTHON=autopy/__init__.py autopy/noindent.py autopy/auto.py
submoda_PYTHON=autopy/submoda/moda.py autopy/submoda/modb.py autopy/submoda/modc.py autopy/submoda/__init__.py
submodb_PYTHON=autopy/submodb/moda.py autopy/submodb/modb.py autopy/submodb/modc.py autopy/submodb/__init__.py`

`autopydir=$(pythondir)/autopy
submodadir=$(pythondir)/submoda
submodbdir=$(pythondir)/submodb`

`dist_bin_SCRIPTS=scripts/script1 scripts/script2 scripts/script3`

This seems to place all my modules and scripts in the appropriate locations, but I wonder if this is "correct", because the way to install python modules seems to be through a setup.py script via distutils. I do have setup.py scripts inside the python modules and scons was invoking them until I marched in with autotools. Is one method preferred over the other? Should I still be using setup.py when I build with autotools? I'd like to understand how people usually resolve builds with c++ *and* python modules using autotools. I've got plenty of other autotools questions, but I'll save those for later.

Comment: Autotools is just terrible. I can't even begin to ... Here is an example read: http://voices.canonical.com/jussi.pakkanen/2011/09/13/autotools/

Comment: Hah. Yes, I've read that one already. I've read a lot of opinions this last week. So far I don't hate autotools though (at least after the first few days of hair pulling), I do hate our current scons implementation.

Comment: Did you consider using cmake? I'm not saying this to be contrary, there are things I honestly don't like about cmake also. But in my experience cmake is a lot less painful than autotools, it mostly just works and it is not too difficult to find helpful info if you have problems. I definitely cannot say this for autotools.

Comment: I did consider using cmake, but it seemed like it might be annoying to require it for installation. Especially considering our software is going to be used a lot on computer clusters where the user doesn't have admin rights or even know much about installing packages at all.

I suppose a part of me also feels a bit invested in autotools, now that I finally kind of get how to use it.

Comment: Not really a question about scons, so perhaps remove that tag..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your description, I would suggest that you have your project built using stock autotools-generated `configure` and `Makefile`, i.e. `autoconf` and `automake`, and have either your `configure` or your `Makefile` take care of executing your `setup.py`, in order to set up your Python bits.

I have a project that's mostly C/C++ code, together with a Perl module. This is very similar to what you're trying to do, except that it's Perl instead of Python.

In my `Makefile` (generated from `Makefile.am`) I have a target that executes the Perl module's `Makefile.PL`, which is analogous to Python's `setup.py`, and in that manner I build the Perl module together with the rest of the C++ code, seamlessly together, as a single build. Works fairly well.

`automake's` `Makefile.am` is very open-ended and flexible, and can be easily adapted and extended to incorporate foreign bits, like these.

Comment: OK, thank you! So keep setup.py, and have it executed via make. If you could elaborate how you do this that'd be great. Would you create an install-hook in a Makefile.am that lives in the python module directories?

Comment: I am assuming "setup.py" does not actually install anything into $(DESTDIR), but that it's analogous to autotools configure script; and additional commands need to be executed in order to install the python modules into $(DESTDIR). In this case, I would use something like "BUILD_SOURCES=python.setup.done" and a rule to build "python.setup.done" as something like "python $(srcdir)/setup.py; touch python.setup.done", then have an install-hook do whatever needs to be done to install the files into $(DESTDIR).